# Image slider in Java - Swing

Tags: java, swing

I want to create something like this http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html but in Java Swing. I don't need all those effects, just scrolling of thumbnail images. Is good approach to use toolbar and ImageIcons, and then on click load image on some JPanel. 
Is there any common practice for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a JPanel with a GridLayout containing a JLabel for each image. Then you can add the panel to a scrollpane. You can turn off the scrollbars so they are not visible.

You can then use the technique described in [Action Map Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/06/action-map-action/) to create buttons to do the scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Kirill Grouchnikov's [Trident animation library](http://kenai.com/projects/trident), in particular [Project Onyx](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/?p=1231), which looks like it might do what you need.

(Edit: It's probably not an out-of-the-box solution, but the library itself looks nice and you could probably adapt some of the example application to suit your needs).