# Java Image slider?

Tags: java, image, swing, slider

I've looked on google & on every page it's all 'Javascript Sliders'. The only link I could find was [Image slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896030/image-slider) & am curious if there is a newer and/or better way of doing this beings that was asked 4 years ago.

If anyone has some tips or knows anything about this thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the images are the same aspect ratio, you might us something like [ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9544652/418556)<sup>1</sup>

Alternately I'd offer a `File` based list (with an appropriate renderer) in the `LINE_START` of a `BorderLayout` that shows the image in a `JLabel` centered in a `JScrollPane` in the `CENTER`.  An example of the 'label in scroll-pane' can be seen in [`ImageViewer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13463684/418556)<sup>2</sup>.

1. [image]
2. [image]